# Azure DevOps Extension Demands

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

To set constraints for an Azure DevOps extension to target Azure DevOps and Azure DevOps Server 2019 and later.

Are these the correct settings

```
  "targets": [
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud"
    },
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server",
      "version": "[17.0,)"
    }
  ]
```

and

```
  "demands": [
    "api-version/5.0"
  ]
```

I could not get the information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest.

Is there a list of targets and demands available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list of supported targets and demands on the [Extension Manifest Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops)

[Installation targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#installation-targets)

> - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud: installs into Azure DevOps Services
> - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server: installs into TFS
> - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services: installs into both. Shortcut for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud and
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server version [14.2,)

[Supported Demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#supported-demands)

| Type | Description | Checked at publish? | Checked at install? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| environment/cloud | Requires running in a cloud environment | Yes | Yes |
| environment/onprem | Requires running in an on-premises environment | Yes | Yes |
| api-version/{version} | Requires a specific API version (minimum) | No | Yes |
| extension/{id} | Requires a specific extension be installed/enabled | No Yes |  |
| contribution/{id} | Requires a specific contribution be available | No | Yes |
| contributionType/{id} | Requires a specific contribution type be available | No | Yes |

Is there any specific reason that the extension should run just on Sevrer 2019 (and not 2020)? If not you the demand towards the api version should be enough (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops#supported-versions)  and select `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services` as target, i.e:

```
"targets": [
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your links point at the same reference that I mentioned... I might be missing something. The information in that page does not include Azure DevOps Server 2019.

Comment: Okay,it was a reply to your question if there was a list of target and demands available, which there is is in the Extension Reference. 

As I understand it you want your extension to run on both Azure Devops Server 2019 and Azure DevOps services? Is there any reason for 2019 only? Why not 2020 for example?

One way to do it is to specify target as `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services` and api-version as `5.0` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops#supported-versions)

Comment: I am trying to target Azure DevOps and Azure DevOps Server 2019 and above... that looks good to me... 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services' and 'api-version/5.0'

Thanks a lot